# Network UNCLAIMED on both ethernet and wifi adapters

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, adapter, pci

Im running ubuntu 20.04 and have a AR9287 wireless adapter installed, I recently did a fresh install of both windows 10 first and then ubuntu. Windiws recognizes the card straight away but ubuntu fails to show any wifi options.

I tried these steps aswell but didnt work: https://itsfoss.com/fix-no-wireless-network-ubuntu/

Connecting to a rounter via ethernet does not work.
Connecting a usb tetherded connection also does not work.

I ran the diagnosis script and described here: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180)

Diagnosis results:
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Q2dtxMkbgv/

Any help is deeply apreciated.

Comment: Kernel modules are not installed for some reason. Was installation interrupted, or an interrupted upgrade?

Comment: Any result from terminal for `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra`

Comment: Install looked finefrom my end. Got the following output: 'ii  linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-27-generic      5.11.0-27.29~20.04.1                  amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.11.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the linux-modules-extra for the current kernel,download [http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.11/linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-38-generic_5.11.0-38.42~20.04.1_amd64.deb](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-hwe-5.11/linux-modules-extra-5.11.0-38-generic_5.11.0-38.42%7E20.04.1_amd64.deb) and copy it to a thumb driver/sdcard and put it on Ubuntu desktop, then double click to install, then reboot